# Checking data integrity with counts

Tags: mongodb

I have a field with a dictionary in it, mapping people to numbers 0-9.

`{peopleDict : {bob: 3, les: 3, meg: 8, sara: 6}}`

I also have another field with another dictionary in it, which is supposed to count the number of people assigned to each number.

`{countDict : {"3" : 2, "8" : 1, "6" : 1}}`

So a document looks like

```
{peopleDict : {bob: 3, les: 3, meg: 8, sara: 6}, 
 countDict : {"3" : 2, "8" : 1, "6" : 1}}
```

I am trying to write a query that tests whether `countDict` actually matches `peopleDict` for each document. I'm sure there must be a way to do this with `aggregate` but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't join data from different collections. So if you have them in separate collections you need to analyze data on application level, or redesign data structure to put all of them to single collection.

Comment: Thanks. They're actually all in the same collection, just different fields. Edited above.